# Filter and sorting on ruby on rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am using the following ActiveRecord query and I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing things.

I have a model that I need to filter and sort.

`Match.where("host_id = #{self.id} OR guest_id = #{self.id}").order('week asc')`

This then gets translated to:

`SELECT "matches".* FROM "matches" WHERE (host_id = 1 OR guest_id = 1).`

This leads me to believe that the sorting is not being done at the database level.

Is there a way of forcing it to sort at the database level without having to write the explicit SQL query?

Is it better for the sorting to be done at the database or after it gets pulled over?

Comment: this is weird. where did you get the sql equivalent?  Try calling `.to_sql` to see what the query translates to sql.

Comment: Definitely better to offload the sorting to the database. That's one of the things ActiveRecord does for you without having to write actual SQL.

Comment: May be this would help you what you want..
http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Comment: Are you pulling the resulting sql from your general query log?

Comment: Shameless plug, for sorting you could use a library I wrote called [sort_this](https://github.com/spullen/sort_this)

Answer (score 0):

use sort / sort_by methods or try  `Match.where("host_id = #{self.id} OR guest_id = #{self.id} ORDER BY week ASC")` 
use .to_sql